# Changing 2011 theme header image based on user dropdown

Tags: php, images, css, headers, theme-twenty-eleven

I posted earlier about changing my site's CSS based on user-choice from a drop-down and storing it in a cookie, which I think I have now resolved, and sort-of have working at the following address http://somethingoriginal.net. However I am trying to change the header image alongside the theme and it is proving much more difficult than I first thought. I  basically want to do this in my header.php file:

```
if(day theme)
 use day css (DONE)
 setDayHeader()
if(night theme)
 use night css (DONE)
 setNightHeader()
```

I have tried calling this from in functions.php which unfortunately does nothing, I know it is being called as I have checked using echo statemnets:

```
    function setDayHeader(){
         //Set header to day header
         $args = array(
         'width'         => 1000,
         'height'        => 288,
         'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalSun.png',
         );
        add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );    


}

function setNightHeader(){
         $args = array(
         'width'         => 1000,
         'height'        => 288,
         'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalTheMoonAndStars.png',
         );
         add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );       
}
```

And tried changing it directly within the HTML of the header.php file, starting here:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
```

by changing the following line:

```
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
```

Either by replacing **header_image()** with a variable or replacing it with a URL directly, but this just seems to make my header image disappear completely. I thought it was best to make a separate post for this as it now addresses different functionality than setting my stylesheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take information from both of your posts to be able to come with something.

Try replacing

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
```

width

```
<?php
if (!(isset($_POST["styles"]))) { //if post not set (first visit)
    if ($_COOKIE["chosenStyle"] == "night") { 
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalTheMoonAndStars.png" width="1000" height="288" alt="Night Header" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalSun.png" width="1000" height="288" alt="Day Header" />';
    }
} else { //if post is set 
    if ($_POST["styles"] == "day") { 
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalSun.png" width="1000" height="288" alt="Day Header" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/SomethingOriginalTheMoonAndStars.png" width="1000" height="288" alt="Night Header" />';
    }   
}
?>
```

just remove you setNightHeader() and setDayHeader() functions